# How can I refresh a form JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I refresh or reload a form using JQuery?

I am filling my form using session values. Using Jquery Post I unset session, but then the values are already filled in the form.

I am trying to reset all form values after un setting the session with the following code:

```
$('#form')[0].reset();
```

Yet it is not working after the $post ajax call.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you have this?

```
<form id="form">.....</form>
```

If you do, it should work. If you don't have an "id" for your form tag, you should use

```
$("form")[0].reset();
```

Answer (score -1):

Note that browser settings also dictate this. Make sure that you have disabled any auto-form filling settings or any plugins.

Answer (score -1):

If you are working in STRUTS-2.0 then you've to do like this for refreshing form reset:

```
<s:submit name="operation" value="Create Account" onclick="location.reload();" />
```